# Find all dangling commits with a given ancestor - Git

Tags: git

I have a repository with a large number of dandling commits. I only want to see those with a particular ancestor. Is this possible?

Comment: I am curious as to the answer, despite not approving of whatever workflow is producing so many dangling commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Here's the general plan:

1. Get a list of all dangling commits.
2. For each dangling commit, do a git log and see if the ancestor is there.

Shell script:

```
particular_ancestor_hash=<40 character hash>
for commit in `git fsck --unreachable|grep 'unreachable commit'|awk '{print $3}'`; do
    if git log --format='%H' $commit|grep -q $particular_ancestor_hash; then
        echo $commit
    fi
done
```